# EPS Base24 system always gives empty response to Python socket client

Tags: python-3.x, iso8583

I recently developed a socket client script in Python which exchanges ISO 8583 messages with EPS Base24 system. However, the Base24 system always gives an empty response. I would like to emphasize that those ISO messages were tested before with some other emulators and Java application and results were successful. So that, the ISO messages' format and structure is right. On the other hand, the team environments supports me to reviewed Base24's logs and we found next message after the ISO message was received by Base24 system:

**"9984 EGLOBAL CRI The expected length of the message exceeds the buffer. End process."**

I was researching about the format to must followed the ISO message and I found that there are some characters that must set before ISO message literal. The kind of characters are:

- Data prefix 0-9 bytes
- IMS/CICS transactions codes 0-9 bytes

But as so far, I do not know which characters must set before literal ISO. However, I checked other application made in Java (where the same message works) and replicate the next function to get two characters which are setting at beginning the ISO message:

```
message_length = len(message)
base_length = 2
ascii_message = ""

for i in reversed(range(base_length)):
    ascii_message = ascii_message + chr(((message_length >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF))
        
return ascii_message
```

The previous function sometimes gives code characters like 1, 195146 or 1, 194175. This depends on message length. But really I do not know what is the reason of this function. I think that the issue is related to this function. On the other hand, the function to connect EPS Base24 system through sockets is:

```
try:
    server = "localhost"
    port = 18080
    _t = (server, port)
    
    print(f"Connecting to server [{_t}]")

    sc.connect(_t)

    # This is only a part of message. So that, the message can have 430 characters even more.
    message = "ISO0260000550200323CC48...."
    
    message = __get_ascii_msg__(message) + message

    print(f"\tSending message [{message}]")

    r = sc.sendall(message.encode())
    sc.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    
    if r is None:
        print(f"\tMessage sent.")

    print("\tReceiving response...")

    response = ""
    while True:
        data = sc.recv(1024)
    
        if len(data) <= 0:
            break
        
        response += data.decode("utf-8")
    
    print(f"\tResponse data [{response}].")
    
    sc.detach()

except socket.error as msg:
    print(f"It could not be created a socket.\nError: [{msg}]")

finally:
    if sc is not None:
        sc.close()
    
    print(f"Socket closed.")
```

I am using:

- Python 3.8
- EPS Base24 R6

I hope to someone can support me with this issue since up to now nobody in my team has been able to resolve this issue. Even not the customer support team itself.

Regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ready, I added more detail about source code. Thanks.